# Finding a shortest path on a circular collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I don't know if my question fully understandable. Generally the thing looks like this:

I have an interactive presentation which draws static images, which creates an animation. When you click the Play button - the animation goes frame by frame - 1 - 72, when 72 is reached the n + 1 frame will be - 1. Now the client wants to have 4 additional buttons which will Play the animation to certain frames for the shortest way - specifically to frames 1, 18, 36, 54 (72 total).

The trick is to find the shortest way for the animation - should it go right (delta == 1), or left (delta == -1).

I've made a fiddle to ilustrate the problem - function PlayShortest is the key. [=Fiddle=](http://jsfiddle.net/9tMcc/3/)

I tried lots of things - switches, route comparision (target - current VS maxFrames - target + current) and nothing seems to work fully properly (at least one path doesn't calculate the optimal route).

Current version of the function looks like this (i know - it's crap but i'm desperate):

```
function PlayShortest(toFrame){
    var delta = 1;
    var diff = Math.abs(toFrame - currentFrame);

    switch(toFrame){
        case 1:
        case 18:
        case 36:
            if(diff < 36)
                delta = -1;
            break;

        case 54:
            if(diff >= 36)
                delta = -1;
            break;
    }

    Play(toFrame, delta);
}
```

If anyone of u guys will be able to solve this problem, you will be my hero :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function PlayShortest(toFrame){
    var delta = 1;
    var diff = currentFrame - toFrame;

    if (diff < -36)
        delta = -1;
    if (diff > 0 && diff < 36)
        delta = -1;

    Play(toFrame, delta);
}
```

Though it'd be better to use maxFrames / 2 instead of 36, in case the frame count changes.

Comment: Looks like it works. I just can't belive it was that simple tho :) I'll accept the answer when i'll test it properly. Thanks :)

Comment: You could do things to reduce the number of lines of code here, but it'd make it less legible. This lays it out in an obvious way.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can calculate the cost of travel in both directions and compare them :

```
var maxFrames = 72;
var pmin = Math.min(currentFrame, toFrame);
var pmax = Math.max(currentFrame, toFrame);
var costForward = pmax - pmin;
var costBackward = pmin + (maxFrames - pmax);
if(costForward <= costBackward) {
  delta = 1;
}else{
  delta = -1;
}
```

Comment: You should omit those min/max calculations, they might reverse the direction. If you are at 50 and want to go to 44, it would say that running forward (from 44 to 50) is better…

Comment: I tried something like this, without success. I pasted your code in to the fiddle mentioned above and not all routes are optimal :(

Answer (score 0):

So if I fully understand you, you just want to know the direction for the shortest way. Therefore you need to calculate the shortest way between "toFrame" and "currentFrame" first.

```
var maxValue = 72;
var delta = 1;

// Going directly and not over the maximum frame 
// would be simply the difference between them  |...1++++2..|
var directWay = Math.abs(currentFrame - toFrame);

// The other way is the path from the bigger frame
// to the max frame plus the smaller frame  |+++1....2++|
var overMaxWay = currentFrame > toFrame ? (maxValue - currentFrame) + toFrame : (maxValue - toFrame) + currentFrame;
```

Now you know which way is shorter and can calculate the direction.

```
// We set delta initially to 1 so you only need to change it, if you
// want to go left, i.e. if the directWay is shorter and the currentFrame 
// bigger than the toFrame |.....2<<<1...| or the overMaxWay is shorter
// and the currentFrame smaller |<<1..........2<<|
if( (directWay < overMaxWay && currentFrame > toFrame) || (directWay > overMaxWay && currentFrame < toFrame) ){
    delta = -1;
}
```

This is surely not the shortest answer, but I hope it helps you to understand, which is IMHO more important than copy pasta. ;)